# To keep Field empty in Html.LabelFor by Default

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Below is the `Html.LabelFor` that i am using

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().Mobile, (string)ViewBag.Mobile, new { @class = "labelvalue" })
```

Is there something i am missing to keep Label empty by Default if there is no value in `(string)ViewBag.Mobile`. 
Because I am getting my Model property Name by default if `ViewBag.Mobile` is empty i.e Mobile instead of empty.

Comment: If the value of `ViewBag.Mobile` is `null`, it will fall back to using the name of the property, and if the value is `string.Empty` then the label element would not even be rendered, which makes sense because what would be the point of a label with no text - you could not even click on it. What is it your trying to achieve?

Comment: in Page i have an option like: Mobile(Html Label)=Value(Which come from DB and assigned it in `LabelFor`) so if value is empty it should not display something..this is what i want to acheive

Comment: If you not displaying a label, then you would not be displaying a control for it either so why not just a `if` block if test `@if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(yourValue) { // render label and control }`

Comment: yup i know this condition but the only thing i was searching to give default value like `Html.TextboxFor`

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you post your ablove comment in different post because `ViewBag.Phone = cmd.ToList()[0].Mobile!=null?cmd.ToList()[0].Mobile:string.Empty;` from your idea works for me..actually i was thinking if condition in `.cshtml`

Comment: But that means no label will be generated at all, and the only reason for generating a `<label>` is to associate it with a form control - which means you have a form control with no label (makes no sense). And if your generating a form control, then use `@Html.DisplayNameFor()`, not `LabelFor()`.

Comment: Not aware of `DisplayNameFor`..so it will render only if there will be some value right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114215/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-steve).